# Jenkins Warning Git permanently add the ECDSA host key for IP address

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, storybook

I created the Jenkins file for the automated checkout branch and deployed Storybook for React micro-frontend. When running the pipeline on Jenkins, it failed and kept saying that “git push origin HEAD: gh-pages. Warning: Permanently added ECSSA host key for IP address ‘11.12.123.123’ to the list of known hosts.”

Truly appreciate for any suggestions to resolve this!

Here is a snippet of my jenkinsfile where it was failing. All the previous stages for setting up are passed.

```
Stage(“build and push storybook”){
  Script{
   Try{
      Sh ‘ls-al’
      Build.install()
      Docker.image(“${BUILD-IMAGE}.inside(‘root’)
      Yarn build-storybook}
    Catch( Exception){throw e}
    Try{
       Commit_and_push(
          Files:[storybook-static]
          Branch: gh-pages}
    Catch( Exception){throw e}
```

Thank you very much for all of your help

I tried creating .ssh/config and added known_host but no luck. I also tried to use the ssh link on checkout git instead of Https, but permission was denied.

I expected the Jenkinsfile to be able to check out the repo, then automate deploy Storybook via the url